# WCF Restful Web Service Client Limits

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, scalability, wcf-rest

I would like to implement a high-traffic restful .NET 4.0 WCF service which can handle a large number (maybe 2,000) requests a minute.

I understand I will need to have the hardware to handle this number of connections, but where can I expect to see bottlenecks when hosting in either IIS or a Windows service?  What sort of configuration options will I need to tweak?

What happens on the server & client sides when the service gets overloaded?  Do clients simply timeout?

Any information on creating a scalable, high-performance WCF rest service would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: do mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Useful Links:

[Using ServiceThrottlingBehavior to Control WCF Service Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
[WCF service may scale up slowly under load(KB)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538826)
[Optimizing WCF Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377061%28BTS.10%29.aspx)